# How to modify x-axis in matplotlib where the numbers are stacked together

Tags: python, matplotlib, stack, axis, subplot

[image]

I wrote code to display the phase portrait of an ordinary differential equation, but the number in my x-axis are stacked together. How could I modify that?

Thank you for your help!! Please see the image.

Here is my code for plotting:

```
    fig2, axs = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize = (7,7))
    for Y in Y0_arr:
        t_exp, Y_Exp = Euler_exp(f,Y,1e-4,T)
        t, Y_imp = Euler_imp(f,Y,1e-4,T)
        t, Y_CN = CN(f,Y,1e-4,T)
        Y_Scipy = odeint(f,Y,t_scipy)
    
        axs[0,0].plot(Y_Exp[:,0],Y_Exp[:,1])
        axs[0,1].plot(Y_imp[:,0],Y_imp[:,1])
        axs[1,0].plot(Y_CN[:,0],Y_CN[:,1])
        axs[1,1].plot(Y_Scipy[:,0], Y_Scipy[:,1])

        axs[0,0].set_title("Euler expilcite")
        axs[0,1].set_title("Euler impilcite")
        axs[1,0].set_title("Crank - Nicolson")
        axs[1,1].set_title("Scipy.integrate.odeint")


    for ax in fig2.get_axes():
        ax.label_outer()

    plt.savefig("Portrait_de_phase_oscillant.pdf")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Some options: choose a larger figsize, or choose a smaller font for the xticks, or rotate the xticks, or force scientific notation.  Once you have chosen which way you want to proceed, a simple search should lead you to the code to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scientific notation for the x-axis. Here is the code:

```
for ax in fig2.get_axes():
    ax.label_outer()
    ax.ticklabel_format(axis = 'x', style = 'sci') #Format tick labels as scientific notation
```